# Displaying desktop and using Lync separately

Tags: window

how can I use Lync when I am projecting my computer. I am not sharing my desktop through Lync, just projecting. But I want to continue to message with Lync but not have that show

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question, you want to project and be able to chat with Lync without that showing on the projector?

If you are using a laptop or a PC with more than one video output, you can press Windows+P and click extend, which give you 2 desktops. Move the windows you need for presenting to one desktop, and Lync to the other,

If you are using a VGA splitter connected to a PC, this won't work as that is still one video output split to 2 different monitors.